# "A agravante ou o agravante?"

Tags: adjetivos, substantivos, gênero

Li certa vez na revista Língua Portuguesa que **"agravante"** e **"atenuante"** são substantivos do gênero feminino. Já o Priberam define como **adjetivo ou substantivo de dois gêneros.**

> - [**Agravante**](https://dicionario.priberam.org/agravante) adjetivo de dois gêneros e substantivo de dois gêneros.
>
>   1. Que ou o que agrava ou torna mais grave (ex.: circunstância agravante; 
>        motivação racista constitui uma/um agravante em todos os crimes). ≠ ATENUANTE
>   2. Que ou o que causa agravo ou ofensa.
>   3. Que ou quem apresenta um agravo em juízo.

Quando "agravante" é classificado como um adjetivo de dois gêneros", entendo que signifique estar correta a concordância do artigo (definido ou indefinido) com o gênero do  substantivo a que "agravante" se refere. Por exemplo:

- "Há **um** fato agravante que precisa ser considerado." (fato = substantivo)
- "O fato de ter ocorrido dolo, é **uma** circustância agravante." (cirunstância = substantivo)

Contudo, quando "agravante" é um substantivo, existem realmente dois gêneros possíveis conforme cita o Priberam?

- "Há um/uma agravante no caso. Ele escondeu tudo de mim."

E fica ao bel-prazer de quem está falando, usar um ou outro gênero? 
Tudo acima é válido também para "atenuante"?

Comment: Como tradutora jurídica, sempre considerei attenuante ligado ao contexto: quando se ve em textos jurídicos portugueses "a atenuante", quase sempre acaba sendo ligado a idea de [uma] circonstância atenuante. https://blook.pt/caselaw/?q=%22atenuantes%22&descriptors=True Por exemplo: Para que se verifique a atenuante especial da provocação,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, de acordo com dicionários os dois gêneros são possíveis.

O [verbete](http://www.aulete.com.br/agravante) do Aulete esclarece bem: o agravante é masculino quando é um **ato**, feminino quando uma **circunstância** e ambos quando se refere à 'parte que entra com recurso de agravo':

> **sm.**
>   5. *Jur.* Ato que aumenta a gravidade de um fato ou de uma situação: *Não socorrer uma pessoa que se atropelou é um agravante do delito*
>
> **sf.**
>   6. *Jur.* Circunstância que torna mais grave a falta ou crime: *A pouca idade da vítima é sem dúvida uma agravante*
>
> **s2g.**
>   7. *Jur.* A parte que entra com recurso de agravo

Descrição também presente no [Dicio](https://www.dicio.com.br/agravante/) (que no entanto usa "ação" ao invés de "ato" para o caso masculino).

Além de "circunstância", a [Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/agravante) cita **causa** como caso feminino de "agravante".

Os verbetes para **atenuante** curiosamente são menos completos, mas eu diria que sugerem o mesmo padrão que para "agravante".

Contudo vale notar que, nos exemplos dados, mais do que essa distinção circunstância/ato, se poderia ver mera concordância com o substantivo que constitui o agravante: idade... uma agravante; crueldade... uma agravante; em que uma oração (e.g., "não socorrer") seria masculino.